# If parent's height div is higher than X, then display this div

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm trying to show a div inside another div, if the parent's height is greather than, let's say 650px:

```html
  <div class="parent">
       <div class="child>this need to be showed if parent's height is greater than 650px</div>
    </div>
```

is there any way to do it with CSS? i searched a lot before asking.

edit: also accept other solutions than CSS, but i would like to know if it is possible.

Thanks!

Comment: Greater than 650px for width or height? This could be done with some js.

Comment: parent's height. post edited!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I know you asked for a method that uses CSS only but your question is tagged with `javascript` - so you get a javascript solution:

#### HTML:

```
<div id="parent">
   <div id="child">This needs to be shown if parent has a height greater than 650px</div>
</div>
```

#### Javascript:

```
function checkHeight() {
  var parentHeight = document.getElementById('parent').clientHeight;
  if (parentHeight > 650) {
    document.getElementById('child').style.display = "block";
  } else {
    document.getElementById('child').style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

`Element.clientHeight` is used to get an elements height including padding but not horizontal scrollbar height, border, or margin. **Read more about it in the MDN documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/clientHeight)**

Whenever you want to check the height of `parent`, call function `checkHeight()`

**UPDATE:** If you are using classes: [See this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kv21qwa5/11)

Comment: only thing is i do need to use class instead of id, since there will be a lot of them

Comment: That's not a problem: https://jsfiddle.net/kv21qwa5/11/ ...I have written the function so that it checks the height of each individual element in the .parent class and decides wether or not to display its (1st) child. Let me know if this is what you needed :D

Answer (score 2):

This can be easily done using JQuery using the `height()` method. I added an ID to your `.child` so that we can use `document.getElementById` to `display:block` and `display:none`

Try the following: (just change the parent height values to above 650px and below 650px to test.)

```js
var parent = $(".parent").height();

if (parent>650) {
 document.getElementById("child").style.display = "block";
}
```

```css
#child {
  display: none;
}

.parent {
  height: 651px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="parent">
   <div class="child" id="child">this need to be showed if parent is greater than 650px</div>
</div>
```

**NOTE:** The height css for parent is purely for testing purposes to see if this code work. Once tested, you can remove that code and let the natural height of the parent class to be there. It is stated in the brackets before the snippet.

Comment: I think OP's question is to do this using CSS not the jquery.

Comment: This will  run only once, and it will work with a hardcoded css height. It does nothing when resizing window.

Comment: Thats not hardcoded css height, its for testing purposes. So if he sets it to 651px, it will show and when he sets it to 649px, it won't show. This is to prove the code works and he can remove that CSS once test is done.

Comment: Please remove the parents height from the css, and then try resizing the window. You will see that it will check for the parents height on load, but if for example you resize the window so that the .parent class will be less then 650px the child will still show up.

Answer (score 1):

A Javascript solution that monitors the height of the parent continuously. So in case you insert any additional elements via Ajax into the parent, the child will be displayed as soon as the set height limit is reached.

```js
const parent = document.getElementsByClassName("parent")[0];
const child = document.getElementsByClassName("child")[0];
document.addEventListener("resize", checkParent);
let lastHeight = 0;
/* 
  The button and #demo are for demonstration purpose only
*/
const demo = document.getElementById("demo");
const button = document.getElementsByTagName("button")[0];
button.onclick = () => demo.style.height = "101px";

function checkParent() {
  const parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;
  /* 
    For the sake of example a height of 100 is used
    This can obviously be set to any desired value
  */
  if (parentHeight >= 100) child.style.display = "block";
}

/* 
  Monitor the height of parent continuously
*/
function checkForChanges() {
  const parentHeight = parent.clientHeight;
  if (parentHeight != lastHeight) {
    checkParent();
    lastHeight = parentHeight;
  }
  setTimeout(checkForChanges, 500);
}

checkForChanges();
```

```css
.child {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">this need to be showed if parent's height is greater than 100px</div>
  <!-- demo is only used to demonstrate the functionality -->
  <div id="demo"></div>
  <button>Click me</button>
</div>
```